# How do I write the % symbol in KaTeX (in Notion)?

Tags: symbols, katex

I tried using backslash but it still just appears as a comment instead of a percent sign, and the same happens for '\qty{70}{%}' or '\qty{70}{\percent}', along with an "Undefined control sequence: /qty" error message. I'm new to this and currently only use this in Notion so bear with me if I don't know some basics.

Comment: Minimal example please. `\%` should in principle work. (welcome!)

Comment: Sorry, but a remark such as "it doesn't work for me" isn't actionable. Please be more specific about *what* isn't working. E.g., do you get error and or warning messages? If so, what do they say? Or, are you getting symbol *other than* `%`? And why aren't you writing either `\qty{70}{\%}` or `\qty{70}{\percent}`? (Note that `\SI` is obsolete and should be replaced with `\qty`.)

Comment: Notion uses KaTeX, which is off-topic on the site. That said, also in KaTeX `\%` should work.

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
70\% does work and also \qty{70}{\percent} and even the deprecated \SI{70}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[KaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/katex/info) problems not reproducible with LaTeX would be off-topic here. However, if I write `70\%` in the example input on https://katex.org/ I also get the correct result:

[image]